# Why are static variables not allowed inside Java methods as they are in C/C++ functions?

Tags: java, c++, c, variables

In **C** and **C++** you can do:

```
void foo()
{
   static int i = 0;
   ++i;
}
```

but, in **Java** you get a `'Illegal modifier for parameter'` error for this:

```
public void foo()
{
    static int i =0;
   ++i;
}
```

I'm not looking for reasons as to why or why not this is a good/bad idea.  I'm just curious why this is legal in **C/C++**, but not **Java**.

Comment: Because they are different languages & James Gosling didn't like `static` as much as Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: Why not? And what would it mean?

Comment: @Alok Save No doubt, thanks for that.  I'm wondering why on this point the rationale is different and what that rationale might be.

Comment: Just an other feature java does not have. static variables always belong to the class in java and are visible in the hole class.

Comment: Because that's how the language was defined.  Bear in mind that this language was designed by someone who was certain that `enum` wasn't useful.

Comment: Programming theory question here: `static` in C/C++ allow to retain state over two invocations; with Java you can do this using various mechanisms; the common particularity is that some state is retained into the "functional unit". Isn't that what is more generally called closures?

Comment: @bn. SO isn't, in general, a good place to ask for design decision rationales. An overwhelming majority of the members aren't designers of *any* language, much less of ones people are likely to asking about. There are exceptions, notably C# thanks to Eric Lippert's contributions; as well as some libraries whose maintainers are active members. But in general, the answers you're likely to get will be more or less educated guesses, or "because someone made that call and not the other one".

Comment: @fge Not even close. `static` in C++ is a way to scope the name of a **global** variable to its enclosing method. This is a purely lexical issue. Closures are a reification of the state of a single given method invocation at runtime, which can then be retained and used somewhere else.

Comment: @millimoose I fail to see a fundamental difference however, in the sense that using `static` in C/C++ is sort of a "singleton closure"

Comment: @fge If you're peing that pedantic about definitions, then yes, it is some sort of closure, insofar as any resolution scope that contains free variables (i.e. references to `static` variables) must be closed over by some other scope (the definitions of those `static`s at the function or module level). Colloquially, however, "closures" in the context of programming language features usually means being able to refer to local state of a function invocation other than the current one, and it's confusing to conflate the now common colloquial meaning with a mangled rephrasing of the formal one,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is a feature poor language.  It is reluctant to add features other than the simplest set which will allow you to write good programs.  This means many obscure features and even some very useful ones available in other languages are not available in Java because there is usually another way to do the same thing, or a better way or they have decided that it's a functionality you would be better off without.

In this case I suspect it is because you can just place the field outside the method and do much the same thing.

BTW: Java does have method local named classes, which are rarely used and Java didn't really need if they were being minimalist. ;)

Comment: Wild Guessing on the named inner classes: there's an argument to be made for banning them introducing irregularity in the language. So it seems like a consistency vs. "feature poverty" tradeoff.

Comment: Java is still complicated enough that many developers don't understand all it's features very well.  Having a language like C++ which gives you many ways of doing the same thing is better for very experienced developers, but is scary in teams of mixed ability.  You end up having to put in place the kind of restrictions Java places on you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`static` function scope variables are useful in C++ to avoid 'static initialization order fiasco'. It's not necessary in Java, since it has well specified order of static initializations.

I guess it's good to avoid these variables, since it leads to confusing behavior:

```
some_code();
static int x = something();
some_code();
```

where `something()` is called only on first invocation, while other instructions are called anytime you use this function.

Also, features are not implemented by default.