# Why java doesn't allow initializing static variable inside a method?

Tags: java, c++

I know that C++ supports static variables in a method and in java, static members are shared among all objects.but why this code fails to compile in java?

```
class Learn
{
 static int count = 0;
 Learn(int n)
 {
    count+=n;
 }
 public void method()
 {
    static int count =0;
 }
}
public class th
{
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
    Learn l = new Learn(4);
  }
}
```

Comment: The most obvious is that your missing the `public` class declaration

Comment: You can't declare a `static` variable inside a method body.

Comment: Because the language designers decided it that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why there is no local static variable in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274375/why-there-is-no-local-static-variable-in-java)

Comment: also see [Why are static variables not allowed inside Java methods as they are in C/C++ functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14296211/1281433)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't allow you to initialize static variables inside methods because variables initialized methods are destroyed after the method has been called, and a static variable is not only accessible outside the method but outside the class. Those two ideas are conflicting.

Comment: It helps :) but why it is allowed in c++ ?

Comment: Well, I don't know C++, so I can't help you there. Are variables declared inside methods accessible outside of the method?

Comment: @kalimba I believe it is an artifact from C, where there are no classes. It was a way for a function to have state without creating globals.

Comment: @clcto: You can write perfectly good modern C++ code without any class. C++ supports various programming paradigms.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I disagree. I don't think you can write modern C++ code without `std::string` or the STL.

Comment: @clcto: Well, but those are not classes in the OOP sense. You don't derive from them, and they have no virtual functions. In fact, most modern C++ has little to do with inheritance and virtual functions. And the STL is, at its heart, a system of interacting concepts, compatible with arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow you to declare a `static` local variable, such as the `count` you're declaring in `method`.  If you want to initialize the `static` class variable, then in `method`, replace

```
static int count =0;
```

with

```
count = 0;
```

Comment: Yeah i know that but my question is 'why that so?' is there a difference between the way in which static variables are used in c++ and java?

Comment: There is no such concept as a `static` local variable in Java.  Java only allows the `final` modifier on local variable declarations, and nothing else such as `static`.

Comment: This would not work the same way as C++.  Count would be 0 every time method() is called, not just the first time, which I believe the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you declare the static variable outside the method to have the same effect as declaring it static inside the method in C++.

I know that using static outside a method in C++ gives the variable "file scope", but java is different.

If you need a few lines of code to initialize the variable, then use an anonymous static method to initialize it when the class loads

```
static {
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure "anonymous static method" is a thing. I think they call it a static initializer, or static block informally.

Comment: Agreed, "static initializer" is the proper term for sure.  Without an example the term is easy to confuse with a method used for something like "static count = initCount()".  So "anonymous static method" is my description, not the term.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C++, Java doesn’t support static local variables. Because In Java, a static variable is a class variable (for whole class). All methods are declared inside the class, Its not possible to declare member function or any variables outside a class. Even main() method should be inside a class. So if we have static local variable (a variable with scope limited to function), it violates the purpose of static. Hence compiler does not allow static local variable.